# How to prevent iOS kill my app when downloading content in the background?

Tags: ios

I am trying to download content when my app is in the background. Referring to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW5, I create the configuration object using the backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier: method of NSURLSessionConfiguration, and it indeed works. But iOS kills my app in 1 minute after my app goes to the background.

I also test using a sample app  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleBackgroundTransfer/Introduction/Intro.html, and it won't be killed when downloading in the background. My app uses about 10M memory, so I think it is not too much so that iOS kills it to save memory. If my app doesn't download content in the background, iOS won't kill it.

How to prevent iOS kill my app when downloading content in the background? Thanks.

Comment: _If your app is terminated while transfers are ongoing, the system continues the transfers in the background and launches your app (as appropriate) when the transfers finish or when one or more tasks need your app’s attention_ It doesn't guarantee your app will live in the background.

Comment: Why do you care if your app gets terminated?  The whole point of using a background session is that your app gets automatically relaunched in the background to handle the data whenever the transfer finishes.